# Composition of functions, notation and order confusion.

Tags: functions, permutations, function-and-relation-composition, permutation-cycles

I thought composition of functions was something that I learned long ago and had down.

However, recently I've been terribly confused by the following.

We are dealing with permutations and my professor writes (for example):

$1 \xrightarrow{\sigma} 2 \xrightarrow{\tau} 8$, and calls this $\sigma \circ \tau$.
$\therefore (\sigma \circ \tau)(1) = 8$.

This can also be written as $\tau (\sigma(x))$.
This makes sense to me following the arrow notation, but initially I tried:

$\sigma(\tau(x))$ which gave the incorrect results, this is because I have historically been taught that:
$(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$.

For example: $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x + 1$, then $(f \circ g)(x) =(x+1)^2$.

Where is the confusion coming in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation of your professor is indeed **inconsistent** as $\sigma\circ\tau$ usually should mean $x\mapsto\sigma(\tau(x))$.

However, specifically for permutations one may prefer the dual operation that reads the composition from left to right, but to distinguish it's usually denoted by some other symbol like $\sigma;\tau:=\tau\circ\sigma$ or $\sigma\cdot\tau$ or simply $\sigma\tau$.

Comment: It was reading it as $((x)\sigma)\tau$

Comment: I personally also prefer this direction, however wouldn't mix notations.

Answer (score -2):

There is a mistake in the two Greek letters above the arrows. From 1 to 2 it should be tau, from 2 to 8 it should be sigma. This mistake is the source of the confusion here.

Comment: But from the given data $\sigma(1) = 2$ and $\tau(2) = 8$.

Comment: $(f\circ g)(x)$ means first applying g then f. Permutation is a function also. I am telling you, the source of confusion is a mistake. It doesn't matter if you write it with arrows or as a function output with brackets. More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

Comment: Then it should be $(\tau\circ\sigma)(1)=8$ and the Greek letters above the arrows are correct. Next time please provide all information in the first post.